# React Copy Paste Permission Alert

Tags: reactjs, alert

I have developed a react app, I have added copy+paste property to my app. When I copy an component then paste, the component is pasted but an alert occurs: localhost:3000 wants to do that: showing the texts and images copied to clipboar. Accept or Decline. I dont want to see this alert. I have seen some online designers which has copy+paste property and it does not show this alert. How can I use this property without seeming this alert. thanks.

Comment: Hi. Can't really help you if you don't provide any details or information. What are you using to copy to the clipboard? Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example and try to provide specific details as to where you're stuck. Cheers.